# I got the answer for $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1}$, but only by a mistake - how do I solve correctly?

Tags: calculus, indeterminate-forms

This is what I did for:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1}$$

1. Check form: $\left({\infty \over \infty}\right)^{\infty}$.
2. Apply L'Hospital's Rule to just $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}$:
   $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {3 \over 3} = 1$$
3. So form in step 1, is really $1^{\infty}$.
4. Take the natural log to bring the exponent down:
   $$\begin{align} \\
   & \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} ln\left[{\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1}\right] \\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space (3x+1) \cdot ln\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right) \\
   \end{align}$$
5. Check form: $\infty \cdot 0$.
6. Rearrange it into quotient form:
   $$ = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {ln\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right) \over {1 \over 3x+1}}$$
7. Check form: $0 \over 0$
8. Apply L'Hospital's Rule and simplify:
   $$\begin{align} \\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{1 \over {3x-2 \over3x+4}} \cdot {(3x+4)(3)-(3x-2)(3) \over (3x+4)^2} \over {(3x+1)(0)-(1)(3) \over (3x+1)^2}}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{1 \over {3x-2 \over3x+4}} \cdot {18 \over (3x+4)^2} \over {-3 \over (3x+1)^2}}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{18 \over (3x-2)(3x+4)} \over {-3 \over (3x+1)^2}}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {18(3x+1)^2 \over -3(3x-2)(3x+4)}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{6(3x+1)^2 \over (3x-2)(3x+4)}\\
   \end{align}$$
9. Check form: ${\infty \over {\infty \cdot \infty}} = {\infty \over \infty}$.
10. Apply L'Hospitals Rule again and simplify:
    $$\begin{align} \\
    & =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{12(3x+1)(3) \over (3)(3)}\\
    &&\\
    & =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{4(3x+1)}\\
    &&\\
    & =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{4(3x+1)} = \infty\\
    \end{align}$$
11. This implies $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1} = e^{\infty} = \infty$.

But this is wrong, the above work is from me double checking my work and finding an error. I did have the correct answer originally (not in the above work), but with the wrong work to find it. Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong in the original work and where I went wrong above?

---

The original:

1. Check form: $\left({\infty \over \infty}\right)^{\infty}$.
2. Apply L'Hospital's Rule to just $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}$:
   $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {3 \over 3} = 1$$
3. So form in step 1, is really $1^{\infty}$.
4. Take the natural log to bring the exponent down:
   $$\begin{align} \\
   & \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} ln\left[{\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1}\right] \\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space (3x+1) \cdot ln\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right) \\
   \end{align}$$
5. Check form: $\infty \cdot 0$.
6. Rearrange it into quotient form:
   $$ = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {ln\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right) \over {1 \over 3x+1}}$$
7. Check form: $0 \over 0$
8. Apply L'Hospital's Rule and simplify:
   $$\begin{align} \\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{1 \over {3x-2 \over3x+4}} \cdot {(3x+4)(3)-(3x-2)(3) \over (3x+4)^2} \over {(3x+1)(0)-(1)(3) \over (3x\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}})^2 \tag{ERROR in red}}} \\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{1 \over {3x-2 \over3x+4}} \cdot {18 \over (3x+4)^2} \over {-3 \over (3x\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}})^2}}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {{18 \over (3x-2)(3x+4)} \over {-3 \over (3x\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}})^2}}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space {18(3x\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}})^2 \over -3(3x-2)(3x+4)}\\
   &&\\
   & = \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{6(3x\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}}) \over (3x+4)}\\
   \end{align}$$
9. Check form: ${\infty \over \infty}$.
10. Apply L'Hospitals Rule again and simplify:
    $$\begin{align} \\
    & =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{6(3) \over (3)}\\
    &&\\
    & =\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{6}\\
    &&\\
    \end{align}$$
11. This then works out to $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} {\left({3x-2 \over3x+4}\right)}^{3x+1} = e^{-6}$

$e^{-6}$ is the correct answer, but I thought there was probably a better way to solve this then the approach I took so I reviewed it and then found the error. Me stumbling onto the right answer was an accident. When I tried to fix the error I get the wrong answer. Can anyone make sense of this for me and show me what I'm doing wrong, and how to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: In step 2, when you applied L'Hopital's Rule to $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{4x-2}{3x+4}$ you should have gotten $\dfrac{4}{3}$ instead of $1$.

Comment: It seems some of your "$4$"'s should be "$3$"'s.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 (and @DavidMitra) I made a mistake writing the problem, should be 3x and 3x, not 4x and 3x.

Comment: Where did you learn $\LaTeX$?

Comment: The derivative of $(3x - 2)(3x - 4)$ is not $(3)(3)$.

Comment: @Brad, I used it on Coursera.org forums before, but also looked at: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are good until here where you take an incorrect derivative of the denominator.

\begin{align} \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space -{6(3x-1)^2 \over (3x-2)(3x+4)}
\end{align}

You don't even have to apply L'Hopitals rule here, you can just compare the coefficients of the $x^2$ terms. Don't forget the negative.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} -\frac{6(3x-1)^2}{(3x-2)(3x+4)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} -\frac{\color{red}{54}x^2-36x+6}{\color{red}{9}x^2+6x-8} = -\frac{54}{9} = -6$$

Comment: What do you mean by, "you can just compare the coefficients of the $x^2$ term?"

Comment: @Matt: in a limit to infinity of polynomials in fractions, only the highest-degree coefficients matter for each polynomial, e.g.:  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{5x^2+3x-7\over 7x^2-75000x+2}=\frac 57$$

Comment: Ah, thanks. So also, if I didn't take the wrong derivative of the denominator I would have ended up with $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}-{36(3x+1) \over 18x+6}$$ ($\infty\over\infty$) so after another L'Hospital Rule: $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}-{108 \over 18} = -6$$

Comment: "Just compare the coefficients" is not a valid reason. Yes, the limit only depends on the leading coefficients for rational polynomials where the numerator and denominator have the same degree -- but why? One way to see it is with L'Hospital. Another way is to divide through by the highest degree monomial (here, $x^2$).

Answer (score 7):

Note that the derivative of the denominator $(3x-2)(3x+4)$ is not $(3)\cdot (3)$, but something else. There is no case of L'Hopital of $\frac{\infty}{\infty\cdot\infty}$, only a case of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Alternative answer. Write it as:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{6}{3x+4}\right)^{3x+1}$$

Let $z=\frac{3x+4}{6}$ Then $3x+1=6z-3$ so this is:

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{6z-3}$$

Now, $\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^z\to e^{-1}$ and $\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-3}\to 1$. So the limit is $e^{-6}$.

Comment: Regarding, "no case of L'Hopital of $\frac{\infty}{\infty\cdot\infty}$". I thought conceptually the denominator would be infinity in this case. It does appear that I can apply L'Hospital's rule and take the derivative and get the correct answer (though perhaps an unnecessarily long way). Is this another case of it leading me to the right answer "by mistake?" See [my comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/860549/156019)

Comment: If your limit is of the form $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)h(x)}$$ with $f,g,h\to\infty$ then you can apply L'Hopital to take the limit $$\frac{f'(x)}{(g(x)h(x))'}$$ But that's treating $g(x)h(x)$ as one function, not treating them as separate entities. $(g(x)h(x))'\neq g'(x)h'(x)$.

Comment: Fair enough, in my attempt in the comment link above, I did take the derivative of the entire denominator by using the power rule (of course I made the mistake you are talking about in the original post, but not intentionally. I should know better).

Answer (score 4):

Starting with

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3x-2}{3x+4}\right)^{3x+1}$$

we modify it to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-6}{3x+4}\right)^{3x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{6}{3x+4}\right)^{3x+4}\cdot\left(1-\frac 6{3x+4}\right)^{-3}$$

which immediately reduces by $y=3x+4$ to

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1-\frac 6y\right)^y\cdot\left(1-\frac 6y\right)^{-3}=e^{-6}\cdot 1^{-3}=e^{-6}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd tackle the problem: this way has the advantage of not needing L'Hopital at all (as long as you know the classic limit definition of $e$).  We have a denominator of $3x+4$, which is a really inconvenient value, so let's make a change of variables and set $y=3x+4$; then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ translates to $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}$, and our expression becomes $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{y-6}{y}\right)^{y-3}$.  Now we can simplify the expression in parenthesis: $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{(-6)}{y}\right)^{y-3}$ = $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{(-6)}{y}\right)^{y}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{(-6)}{y}\right)^{-3}$.  By using the standard limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left (1+\frac xn\right)^n = e^x$ the left term evaluates to $e^{-6}$, and of course the right term goes to $1^{-3}=1$.

Comment: Many of you substitute using the ${y-6 \over y}$ like pattern. How do you see this? It's been a long time since I have had algebra. I see what you are doing now, but I would never have thought to do that. Does this kind of thing have a name and a way of knowing where you can utilize it? Or, is this just a creative thing that one can apply when they need it?

Comment: @Matt It's mostly pattern recognition (and I'll edit this into my answer later): seeing that the leading terms in the fraction are the same ($3x$ in both numerator and denominator) suggests that the fraction can be written as $1+f(x)$ for some $f()$ that goes to zero, and so the overall limit can be written colloquially as $(1+0)^\infty$, which is a good candidate for trying to bring into the form of the classical exponential limit.